# Extract hyperlink and text from rtf file?

Tags: python, hyperlink, rtf, text-extraction

- `rtf_to_text` is reading text from file and escaping Hypertext. Is there any python module available to read text and hypertext from rtf file?

---

```
with open(r"C:\Users\Documents\file_name.rtf") as infile:
            content = infile.read()
            text = rtf_to_text(content)
            print(text)
```

Input:-Get the latest news at ndtv.com

Current_ouput :- Get the latest news at

Desired_Output-Get the latest news at ndtv.com

Answer (score 0):

Use [pyth3](https://pypi.org/project/pyth3/) library for reading RTF files.

Code:

```
from pyth.plugins.rtf15.reader import Rtf15Reader
from pyth.plugins.plaintext.writer import PlaintextWriter

with open(filename, "rb") as rtf_file:
    doc = Rtf15Reader.read(rtf_file)

text = PlaintextWriter.write(doc).getvalue()
```

Hope this helps!